# Function overload, inheritance and implicit constructor : weird priority

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++11, overloading

Here is a test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#define OPTION 1

template<typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
        Base() : _x() 
        {std::cout<<"Base()"<<std::endl;}

        Base(const T& source) : _x(source) 
        {std::cout<<"Base(const T& source)"<<std::endl;}

        Base(const Base<T>& source) : _x(source.x) 
        {std::cout<<"Base(const Base<T>& source)"<<std::endl;}

    public:
        inline void set(const T& source) 
        {std::cout<<"Base::set(const T& source)"<<std::endl; 
        this->_x = source;}

        inline T get() const 
        {std::cout<<"Base::get(const T& source)"<<std::endl; return _x;}

    protected:
        T _x;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
    public:
        Derived() : Base<T>() 
        {std::cout<<"Derived()"<<std::endl;}

        Derived(const T& source) : Base<T>(source) 
        {std::cout<<"Derived(const T& source)"<<std::endl;}

        Derived(const Derived<T>& source) : Base<T>(source) 
        {std::cout<<"Derived(const Derived<T>& source)"<<std::endl;}

    public:
        #if OPTION == 0
        inline void set(const T& source) 
        {std::cout<<"Derived::set(const T& source)"<<std::endl; 
        this->_x = source;}
        #endif

        inline void set(const Base<T>& source) 
        {std::cout<<"Derived::set(const Base<T>& source)"<<std::endl; 
        this->_x = source.get();}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived<double> d;
    double x = 4.5;
    d.set(x);
    return 0;
}
```

For me `OPTION 0` and `OPTION 1` would be equivalent but they are not and I would like to understand why.

With `OPTION 0`, when the `main` calls `d.set(x)` the compiler has the choice between `Derived<T>::set(const T& source)` and `Derived<T>::set(const Base<T>& source)` and of course, for `T x` he chooses `Derived<T>::set(const T& source)`.

Now with `OPTION 1`, when the `main` calls `d.set(x)`, I would think that the compiler has the choice between `Base<T>::set(const T& source)` and `Derived<T>::set(const Base<T>& source)`.

But instead of choosing `Base<T>::set(const T& source)`, the compiler (GCC 4.6.3 here) implicitely converts `x` to `Base<T>` and calls `Derived<T>::set(const Base<T>& source)`.

Is it normal ?

And what is the common technique (if it exists) to avoid that (without changing the constructors) in order to have `OPTION 0` and `OPTION 1` equivalent ?

Comment: You should [stop using `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) unless you really mean to flush the stream.

Comment: Of course I don't use std::endl when I need performances, but it is not my point here. But you are right... (nevertheless, for things like log files, std::endl may be more convenient than "\n")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When overloading a function from a base class in a derived class, the base class function is hidden and never chosen by overload resolution unless a `using` declaration is used. That is, to allow the compiler to choose `Base<T>::set(const T&)`, you'd added

```
using Base<T>::set;
```

in your derived class.

Comment: Is this syntax from C++11 or from C++03 ? (get() method solved)

Comment: I think using declarations where introduced with C++ 98.

Comment: Is it working with template functions too ? (and in this case, should I specify the template parameters in the using line ?)

Comment: The `using` declaration makes a name visible, not a signature. I'm not sure if it is possible to make specific signatures visible. It is quite possible that it isn't possible because if you had typed the signature, adding the delegation to the base wouldn't be much of an inconvenience.

Comment: one can apply a trick to avoid bringing up other signatures. `struct Base { void set(int) { cout << "int"; } void set(float) { cout << "float"; } void set(long) { cout << "long"; } }; struct A : Base { using Base::set; void set(int a) { set((float)a); } void set(float a) { /*...*/ }; int main() { A a; a.set(0); a.set(0.f); a.set(0L); }`. This outputs "long", instead of "intlong" (the derived function will hide rather than conflict).